# Python execute HTTP commands

Tags: python, http

To be brief, I've basically found that executing certain strings in the address bar in my browser causes good things to happen for me.
For instance: http://myip:myport/?CreateOrder=Create+New+Order creates a new order in my database.

I've used python to set the variables I want passed into that string, but don't know the correct vocab to be able to figure exactly how to get python to execute that string as if it were a browser.

Sorry for being ignorant. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: start here http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not sure that I entirely understand the context of your question you can make URL requests in python using the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) module, specifically look at the `urlopen` function.

Here is an example of how you could make the request you showed:

```
import urllib2

url_response = urllib2.urlopen('http://myip:myport/?CreateOrder=Create+New+Order')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just dumb --I knew how to store/open the url like that, but didn't even come to the realization that by doing this, python is indeed executing the command

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [`Requests`](http://python-requests.org) module.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params={'foo': 'bar'})

print r.content
```

<sub>([httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org) is a nice service for debugging HTTP requests)</sub>

**Result:**

```
{
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity, deflate, compress, gzip",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "80",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/0.8.3",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": ""
  },
  "args": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "origin": "46.64.26.143"
}
```

Comment: Nice site you mentioned for inspecting HTTP requests :)

Comment: Is there any version of this module for windows?